# TypeError: int object is not iterable when trying to use a list of prime numbers

Tags: python

So I have been writing a function to generate a key as a tuple using randomly generated prime numbers, and when I try to run the code it generates the error(s),

```
PS C:\Users\cinna\workspace\project4> py rsa.py S
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\cinna\workspace\project4\rsa.py", line 104, in <module>
    _main()
  File "C:\Users\cinna\workspace\project4\rsa.py", line 91, in _main
    n, e, d = keygen(25, 100)
  File "C:\Users\cinna\workspace\project4\rsa.py", line 10, in keygen
    primes = _primes(lo, hi)
  File "C:\Users\cinna\workspace\project4\rsa.py", line 69, in _primes
    primes += p
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Edit: Here is my code for keygen(), _primes() and main(). Thanks for the patience, still learning StackOverflow etiquette.

```
def keygen(lo, hi):
    primes = _primes(lo, hi)
    for i in range(lo, hi):
        if _primes(i):
            ptemp = stdrandom.uniformInt(0, len(primes))
            qtemp = stdrandom.uniformInt(0, len(primes))
            p = primes[ptemp]
            q = primes[qtemp]
            n = p * q
            m = (p - 1) * (q - 1)
            while True:
                e = stdrandom.uniformInt(2, m)
                if e % m == 0 and m % e != 0:
                    break
            d = 0
            for a in range(1, m):
                if (e * a) % m == 1:
                    d = a
                    break
    return n, e, d

def _primes(lo, hi):
    primes = []
    for p in range(lo, hi + 1):
        j = 2
        f = 1
        while(j * j <= p):
            if(p % j == 0):
                f = 0
                break
            j = j + 1
        if(f == 1):
            primes += p
    return primes

def _main():
    x = ord(sys.argv[1])
    n, e, d = keygen(25, 100)
    encrypted = encrypt(x, n, e)
    stdio.writef('encrypt(%c) = %d\n', x, encrypted)
    decrypted = decrypt(encrypted, n, d)
    stdio.writef('decrypt(%d) = %c\n', encrypted, decrypted)
    width = bitLength(x)
    stdio.writef('bitLength(%d) = %d\n', x, width)
    xBinary = dec2bin(x, width)
    stdio.writef('dec2bin(%d) = %s\n', x, xBinary)
    stdio.writef('bin2dec(%s) = %d\n', xBinary, bin2dec(xBinary))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    _main()
```

Comment: It's not well accepted to post screenshots of your code, as this makes it difficult for anyone to run your code in their machine to test. Could you rework your code into a minimal working example and edit your post?

Comment: For example, I can't see the `_primes` function, so it's impossible to effectively debug.

Comment: `primes` is a list and `p` is an int... Did you mean `primes.append(p)`?

Comment: @Tomerikoo I was recommended to not use 'primes.append(p)' as this is ahead of what we are working on, but if that will help fix this issue I will try it.

Comment: What do you mean this is ahead? This is the most basic way to add elements to a list... Sounds like a bad course to me if you're working with lists and didn't learn about `append`...

Comment: @Tomerikoo this is for a python course, and the instructor wants us to use functions that we've learned about as of the date the project was assigned. Sorry for being vague.

Comment: No you were not being vague I understood what you mean, I just find it really odd to learn about lists without learning about `append`... How are you supposed to add stuff to them? You could always do `primes += [p]` but..... why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this expression:`primes += p`
You can use that operator, but it works like this:

```
[1,2,3,4] = [1,2,3,4] + x
```

Now x has to be a list so that this expression works. It just concatenates to lists together.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to append an `int` to a `list`, which is illegal. You can append a `list` to a `list`. Try doing `primes += [p]` or `primes.append(p)`.